# Получение полного пути к процессу по ID

Tags: winapi, c++, процесс

Имею ID процесса, отсюда могу найти его хендл, нужно найти полный путь к файлу, пока из примеров Майкрософт удалось только получить название файла с расширением, а нужно полный путь, включая название. Может кто направить на путь истинный?

Код:

```
 std::string FunctionalSet::GetProcCommandLine(_int32 ProcessID)
 {

 HANDLE hProcessSnap;

 PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return ("0");
}

pe32.dwSize = sizeof (PROCESSENTRY32);

Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32);

do
{
    if (pe32.th32ProcessID == ProcessID)
    {
        return pe32.szExeFile;
    }

} while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

return ("0");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение:

```
GetModuleFileNameEx
```

Я думал, что эта функция будет доступна из библиотеки `windows.h`.

Я подключил следующую библиотеку и все заработало

```
#include  < Psapi.h>
```

Процедура, которая принимает ID и возвращает полный путь к процессу.

Код:

```
  std::string FunctionalSet::GetProcCommandLine(_int32 ProcessID)
  {
       setlocale(0, "");
       char path[256] = "";
       HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, ProcessID);
       HMODULE mod;

       EnumProcessModules(pHandle, &mod, sizeof(HMODULE), NULL);

       GetModuleFileNameEx(pHandle, mod, path, 255);

       return path;
  }
```